# Van Kampen Theorem when $A \cap B$ is a circle bounding discs from $A$ and $B$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> We are given a finite path-connected simplicial complex $X = A \cup B$, where $A$, $B$ and $A \cap B$ are sub-simplical complexes.
>   If $A \cap B$ is homeomorphic to a circle and bounds discs in each of $A$ and $B$, what can be said about the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ in terms of the fundamental groups of the subspaces.

My thoughts:

I tried to find inspiration from the sphere, but $\pi_1(A) = \pi_1(B) = \{e\}$ in this case so this example doesn't help too much.
Anyway, we have $\pi_1(A \cap B) = <c> \cong \mathbb{Z}$, where $<c>$ denotes the free group on one letter, I've chosen $c$.
Suppose that $\pi_1(A) = <a_1,...,a_n | r_1,..r_p>$ and $\pi_1(B) = <b_1,...,b_m | s_1,..s_q>$.

Next, we need to work out homomorphisms $i_1: \pi_1(A \cap B) \to \pi_1(A) $ and $i_2: \pi_1(A \cap B) \to \pi_1(B) $ to get relation $i_1(c) = i_2(c)$.

I suppose this is where the fact that $A \cap B$ bounds a disc comes in, I *think* the idea here is that the homomorphisms give us the relation $a_i = b_j$ for some $i,j$ (honestly this is just a stab in the dark.)

So $\pi_1(X) = <a_1,.a_{i-1},a_{i+1},..,a_n,b_1,...,b_m | r_1,..r_p,s_1,..s_q>$

My main problem here is understanding what the significance of $A \cap B$ bounding discs in $A$ and $B$ is?

Thanks!

Comment: Since $A\cap B$ bounds disks in both $A$ and $B$, it follows that $i_1$ and $i_2$ are the $0$ homomorphisms. Then the relation "$i_1(c) =i_2(c)$" actually just says "$0=0$", in other words there is *no* relation coming from the intersection.

Comment: Ah thank you! I have been trying to thinkmore about what the inclusion homomorphisms $i_1$ and $i_2$ are actually doing, are these the $0$ homomorphisms because any loop in $A \cap B$ when mapped into $A$ resp $B$ using $i_1$ resp $i_2$ can be "shrunk" to a point because of the $A \cap B$ bounding a disc thing? Is this the idea here?

Comment: Yes, Dylan, that's exactly the way to think about it.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks to both of you for your help.